# Is it possible to make sql join on several fields using peewee python ORM?

Tags: python, peewee

Assuming we have these three models.

```
class Item(BaseModel):
    title = CharField()

class User(BaseModel):
    name = CharField()

class UserAnswer(BaseModel):
    user = ForeignKeyField(User, 'user_answers')
    item = ForeignKeyField(Item, 'user_answers_items')
    answer = ForeignKeyField(Item, 'user_answers')
```

I want to get all `Items` which does not have related `UserAnswer` records for current user. In SQL it would be something like this:

```
select * from item i
left join useranswer ua on ua.item_id=i.id and ua.user_id=1
where ua.id is null;
```

Is it possible to make a left outer join with constraint on two fields using peewee syntax? It will be cool if I can do it in this way:

```
Item.select().join(UserAnswer, JOIN_LEFT_OUTER, on=['__my_constraints_here__']).where(
    (UserAnswer.id.is_null(True))
)
```

Answer (score 13):

Yes you can join on multiple conditions:

```
join_cond = (
    (UserAnswer.item == Item) &
    (UserAnswer.user == 1))
query = (Item
         .select()
         .join(
             UserAnswer,
             JOIN.LEFT_OUTER,
             on=join_cond))
         .where(UserAnswer.id.is_null(True)))
```

Docs here: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#Query.join

Sorry there is not an example of using multiple join conditions, but the `on` is just an arbitrary expression so you can put any valid peewee "Expression" you like there.

Important: you should import JOIN - `from peewee import JOIN`

Comment: Thanks for answer @coleifer. I tried your suggestion, but I get an error. Peewee generates wrong sql with this join condition

Comment: It makes this sql `SELECT 't1'.'id',  't1'.'description' FROM 'item' AS t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN 'useranswer' AS t2 ON (('t2'.'item_id' = 'item' AS t1) AND ('t2'.'user_id' = %s)) WHERE ('t2'.'id' IS %s) [1, None]`. It has an error in on clause `ON (('t2'.'item_id' = 'item' AS t1)`. It must be `ON (('t2'.'item_id' = 't1'.'id')`. What I must do to make it work?)

Comment: Then make it be `(UserAnswer.id == 1)` instead of `(UserAnswer.user == 1)`. I bet if you looked at it and thought about it you'd have been able to figure it out!