# Peewee / SQLite Query for 7 Day Rolling Average

Tags: python, sqlite, peewee

I have a table of daily sessions and units sold for each product

```
ProductId (char) | Date | Sessions | UnitsSold
sku01 | 2017-02-01 | 21 | 4
sku01 | 2017-02-02 | 14 | 3
sku01 | 2017-02-03 | 13 | 3
sku01 | 2017-02-06 | 14 | 2
sku01 | 2017-02-07 | 5 | 1
sku01 | 2017-02-09 | 2 | 0
sku02 | 2017-02-02 | 16 | 10
sku02 | 2017-02-03 | 16 | 10
sku02 | 2017-02-14 | 30 | 23
...
```

I'm trying to generate a report for each product that gives the last 7 days rolling average for each day for the sessions and units sold values

So for example the output for sku01 would be:

```
Date | SessionsRollingAvg | UnitsSoldRollingAvg
2017-02-01 | sra1 | usra1
2017-02-02 | sra2 | usra2
...
```

where:

```
sra1 = (sum of Sessions 2017-02-01 to 2017-02-07 for sku01) / 7
usra1 = (sum of UnitsSold 2017-02-01 to 2017-02-07 for sku01) / 7
sra2 = (sum of Sessions 2017-02-02 to 2017-02-08 for sku01) / 7
usra2 = (sum of UnitsSold 2017-02-02 to 2017-02-08 for sku01) / 7
```

So far I found [this article](https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/rolling-average.html) that mentions multiple ways to do it with Postgres, MySQL. But how can I do it with the Peewee ORM?

Answer (score 1):

Start your query from your products class then you can specify a join condition to select the sessions you want.  See this answer [Is it possible to make sql join on several fields using peewee python ORM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29244434/is-it-possible-to-make-sql-join-on-several-fields-using-peewee-python-orm)

You can then use fn and group_by to create your average.

Something like this more or less matches the queries described in your article:

```
from peewee import fn

cond = (
    (MySessions.product_id == MyProduct.id) & 
    (MySessions.date.between(7daysago, now))
)

query = (MyProduct
         .select(MyProduct, fn.avg(MyTable.Sessions).alias('session_avg')
         .join(MySessions, on=cond)
         .group_by(MyProduct)
```